# MySQL Statement with comma-separated list and SELECT IN

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a possibility to make a cross statement like this:

```
SELECT name FROM branchen WHERE id IN (SELECT value FROM metadata WHERE user_id=XX AND metakey = 'branche')

Result is:
Branche A
```

this result returns only the first value of "branchen".
I will have a result like:

```
SELECT name FROM branchen WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)

Result is:
Branche A
Branche B
Branche C
```

Seems that I must convert the SELECT Statement to a string value?

```
SELECT value FROM metadata WHERE user_id=XX AND metakey = 'branche'
Result is: 
1,2,3
```

Yes, it will be better if the value is saved as own values in the table. I will not change the structure at the moment, so maybe anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `value` is a STRING, not a NUMBER.  Because the `IN` comparison is to a number, it gets converted to a number.

The real fix is to fix the data model, so you are not storing numbers in strings.  But assuming you are stuck with a really bad data model, you can use `find_in_set()` instead:

```
SELECT b.name
FROM branchen b
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM metadata md
              WHERE md.metakey = 'branche' AND
                    find_in_set(b.id, md.value) 
             );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works great! - Yes it is not the best way, but in my option the workaround solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_split` function

```
declare @ids varchar (100);

SELECT @ids = value FROM metadata WHERE user_id=XX AND metakey = 'branche'

SELECT name FROM branchen WHERE id IN (select value from string_split(@ids, ','));
```

If you using mysql then you can use find_in_set.

`string_split` - this method split the string on given separator.